# How to change path for build project in angular?

Tags: build, angular-cli

Here my project name is `angulardemo` so I build project using this command

```
ng build --prod --base-href /angulardemo/
```

so this command build project and create dist folder and inside dist folder create anglulardemo named folder and inside angulardemo folder create below files

```
3rdpartylicenses.txt
favicon.ico
index.html
main.95e7fd4eb2e659e65554.js
polyfills.1ef83d22ada557f4a131.js
runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js
styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css
```

but I want to create this files directly in dist folder don't want create `angulardemo` folder inside dist folder how It is possible ?

Comment: You had to set your output dir in the angular.json. Here can you edit this option: projects -> your project name -> architect -> build -> options -> outputPath : "dist"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change output path in angular.json

```
{
 "projects": {
   "my-app-name": {
    "architect": {
     "options": {
       "outputPath": "dist", <-----here
```

Answer (score 4):

With the new version of **angular (v6+)** and the **angular CLI** it goes inside the dist `directory/yourproject` by default.

Although you can change **build options** inside `angular.json`:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
```

Comment: You should see how the `assets` and `styles` are referenced in angular.json. fix them, clean your dist and build it again. can you share your angular.json?

Comment: check your `tsconfig.json` outDir. see if it is  "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",